# How register for UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification in iOS 4

Tags: ios4, notifications

This is a real newbie:

Using IOS 4.
How do I register for `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` in several objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS4, applicationWillTerminate does not normally get called for applications that support background execution. That may be why you're having a problem.

If you have that disabled, you can register your objects to listen for the UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification notification, and/or override the application delegate's -applicationWillTerminate: method and put your code there:

```
//set up this class as an observer of UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
//so we can intervene when the app is about to exit.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                         addObserver:self
                            selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
                                name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                              object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```